# Should we simplify or not for function domain?

Tags: rational-functions

If $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x}$, what is the domain of $x$?

Should we simplify it to $f(x) = x$ so that $x$ is any real number?

Or we do not simplify it and that the $x$ is any real number and $x \ne 0$.

But depend on the web service such as this [example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=domain+y%3Dx%5E2%2Fx) from Wolfram Alpha, the domain of $x$ does not include 0.

Comment: Do you mean "what is the domain of $f$"? Personally, if I was being *very strict*, I would say that the definition of $f$ was "take $x$, square it, and then divide the result by $x$", which always gives you $x$ back except when $x = 0$, when the calculation doesn't make sense. So the domain is the set of non-zero real numbers. (In practice, I am never this strict, except when I am teaching students how to be this strict.)

Comment: Think of it this way: will your calculator get upset when you try to divide $0^2$ by $0$. Yes it will. So $0$ is not in the domain.

Comment: Technically, you have not defined a function until you have also specified the domain and codomain. And clearly once you have specified a domain, the question of what the domain is becomes moot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual convention in such cases is that the domain of the function is the largest subset of $\Bbb R$ on which the function is defined. Thus, the function $f(x)=\frac{x^2}x$ is not identical to the function $g(x)=x$: while they agree on $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, the domain of $f$, the domain of $g$ is all of $\Bbb R$. Two functions with different domains are by definition not the same function. Thus, in general you may not simplify $f$ to $g$. Of course if you’re only interested in the behavior of $f$ on some subset of $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, then it’s perfectly fine to replace $f$ by $g$, since $f=g\upharpoonright(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\})$.